# Vuejs - debounce via lodash, pass 'wait' argument

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I am trying to make a method which incorporates a debounce (using Lodash), which can have its *wait* parameter dynamically passed.

Here is sample code where I am trying to do this with an input field - it will log 'Hit' every time a user makes an input:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input @input='validateInput1(400)'>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  methods: {
    validateInput1: _.debounce(function() {
      console.log('Hit 1!');
    }, 400),
    validateInput2(delay = 1000) {
        function test() {
          console.log('Hit 2!');
        }
        const doDebounce = _.debounce(test, delay);
        doDebounce();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-wescoff-hs8wi?file=/src/App.vue

I am trying two different ways of achieving this. With **validateInput1** method, I don't see how I can pass in the *wait* parameter.

With **validateInput2** method, I can pass in the *wait* parameter, but the outer **validateInput2** method runs immediately on input, when I need the entire method to run via *wait*. The **validateInput1** method runs the entire method after a delay, but I can't pass in the *wait* parameter with **validateInput1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the code looks very ugly by itself, it just work.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input @input="validateInput2(10)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      debounce: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validateInput2(delay = 1000) {
      if (this.debounce) {
        return this.debounce();
      }

      const deb = _.debounce(function test() {
        console.log("Hit 2!");
      }, delay); // I want to reuse it
      this.debounce = deb;
      return deb();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Though I do understand it looks much clearer to place the delay timeout in the template, instead of script, but definitely my answer seems worse than the `validateInput1` solution you have had.

But anyway, if you can think of how to create a better and cleaner solution, feel free to share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

One (quick) way achieving this is returning a function:

```js
validateInput2(delay = 1000) {
  function test() {
    console.log('Hit 2!');
  }
  const doDebounce = _.debounce(test, delay);
  return doDebounce;
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<input @input="validateInput2(400)()" />
```

What it does: First calling sends the delay. Second is calling composed function on `@input`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. If I hit a key five times rapidly, the function is run five times (it should only have run once). Vuejs is also producing an error: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.validateInput2(...) is not a function"

Comment: `_` is composing a function for you. If you want to be able to send delay you can't do it on `@input` event then. Because it will compose new function every time the event is fired. Like in my example.